# Query matching multiple Ids? Hibernate Search 5

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Hello this query used to work in Hibernate Search 4.2, after upgrading to v5 apparently now it doesn't split the search terms:

```
@Indexed
public class Foo {

  @DocumentId
  private Integer id;

  .....
}

.....

QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Foo.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
  .keyword()
  .onFields("id")
  .matching("123 567")
  .createQuery();
```

In v4, Hibernate Search would create a query matching either of the 2 IDs in the example, however in v5, Hibernate Search no longer splits the "123 567" into 2 terms and treats the whole string as a single value. The same type of query seems to yield the old v4 behavior on any other field that's not the DocumentId.  I've read the migration guide and I haven't seen any mention of this change of behavior. How would you rewrite this query now?

Can someone shed some light on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field mapped as *@DocumentId* needs to be treated as a special case. Since it's also used for deletion (and updates) of the document within the index, it has to be treated as a single keyword to avoid any ambiguity: no Analyzer will be applied to it.

The QueryBuilder DSL automatically pre-processes the *matching()* clause with the same Analyzer as used during the indexing pipeline; since the *id* field is treated as a single, unique keyword the input text is not broken down in this case.

To load entities by *id* I'd generally recommend to use a traditional Hibernate Criteria, not using a full-text query.

If you want to use the full-text query to combine it with other full-text restrictions you can either map the *id* property into an additional *@Field* (on top of @DocumentId) and give it a different name, or you can target each individual *id* with a *TermQuery* and combine all term queries using a *BooleanQuery*.

I suspect it's not mentioned in the migration guide as this was never intended to work like it did in v4. The fact that it no longer works as in older versions is likely the consequence of a bug fix.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the clarification. I dug into the code and it indeed matches what you say. Thank you!